# get specific string that include specific word between specific characters - php

Tags: php

I'm beginner to php and I have no Idea how to solve this.

I have text file that contains paragraphs and links, this is an example from text file:

```
$string = ("Lorem 'Ipsum' is simply: dummy 'http://www.exmplelink1.com/blah/blah/file 1 b.txt' text of the printing 'http://www.exmplelink1.com/blah/blah/file 1 c.txt' and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 'http://www.exmplelink2.com/blah/file.txt' has been, the 'industry's standard'");
```

please notice that there are many single quotes and two domain names in the string: exmplelink1 and exmplelink2

- how do I only get exmplelink1 links (the complete link between single quotes) there are two links in this case:

  ```
  'http://www.exmplelink1.com/blah/blah/file 1 b.txt'
  'http://www.exmplelink1.com/blah/blah/file 1 c.txt'
  ```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [find all urls (links) in text with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065362/find-all-urls-links-in-text-with-php)

Comment: Use regular expressions. Something like `'http.*?'` should work.

Comment: I might add, I really don't know regex :(

Comment: should I replace '?' with the domain name? because I have too many links with different domain names and I only want to get links with specific domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you to get only **exmplelink1** ,use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read you file data as string & then use below code to get you desired **exmplelink1**

```
$re = "/'http:\\/\\/www\\.exmplelink1.*?'/m"; 
$str = ("Lorem 'Ipsum' is simply: dummy 'http://www.exmplelink1.com/blah/blah/file 1 b.txt' text of the printing 'http://www.exmplelink1.com/blah/blah/file 1 c.txt' and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 'http://www.exmplelink2.com/blah/file.txt' has been, the 'industry's standard'"); 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

See For Regex https://regex101.com/r/gE5uX6/2

Comment: May i suggest escaping the dots in hostname in the pattern? Not that it would matter this time but generally...