# Javascript write regular expression to substitute http with html tag

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I make this string text

```
first video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456

second video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8123123`;
```

become

```
first video link: 
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456">
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456
</a>

second video link: 
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8123123">
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8123123
</a>
```

I have written a regular expression to parse the link

Here is what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myString =`first video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456
second video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8123123`; 
var myRegexp = /(https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[0]) // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456
</script>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065386/2575224

Comment: What a strange dupe was chosen by the community script. The problem here is not *matching*, but *replacing*.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know I need to use `replacing` instead of `matching`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following solution:

```js
var myString = "first video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456\nsecond video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8123123"; 
var myRegexp = /https?:\/\/\S+/g;
var match = myString.replace(myRegexp, '<a href="$&"><br>  $&<br></a>');
document.body.innerHTML = match;
```

The `https?:\/\/\S+` will match `http`, then an optional `s`, then `://`, and then `\S+` will match one or more non-whitespace symbols. The whole match value can be inserted into the resulting string within a `String#replace()` replacement pattern via a `$&` backreference.

Answer (score 0):

See [retrieve all matches for a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript) for details on how to access all matches of myRegexp. Your sample code looks like string processing, your problem might be addressed correctly by working on elements of a source html-document or by processing a string and contribute the result into a document.

```
document.createElement('a').href=match[0];
```

Hint: Your regex (/(https|http)?://[\S]+/g) does match "://not.an.url" as well. either just mark the 's' of "https" an optional, or include "://" to the optional protocol part of your expression.

Comment: Why see the linked post if OP needs to *substitute* a string? It is not about *matching*, it is about *replacing*.